# Provisioning Puppet to GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, puppet, gcloud

I have a problem issuing a cert from puppet-agent to puppet-master to sign.

I have followed [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/puppet-in-google-cloud-platform). However, when I run `cmd sudo /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet cert list`
nothing shows.

Could this be because of VPC-network that is preventing both vm instance from communicating? I've research on Puppet to delete all context inside of ssl and did that and restart and still not acknowledgment from the agent to master.

Comment: I've removed the Kubernetes-related tags as this question does not appear related.

Comment: Did you make sure to specify the 'internal' IP address of the puppet-master Compute Engine instance in Step 1 of Section "Install and run the Puppet agent" ? Using internal IP address should make it work.  Moreover, in Section "Sign the certificate...", you can make a manual single sign by running "sudo /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet cert sign puppet-agent.c.YOUR_PROJECT_ID.internal". Please try that to see if that works.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please run puppet agent one-time in verbose mode with `puppet agent -t` on `puppet-agent` node and check the output, it may tell you what is wrong. If it does not then please share it with us, maybe we'll be able to interpret it.

Comment: As much as I would like to move this forward, the project I was working on was abandon but may look into in the near future as I'm still using a VPC network.